# Correct use of LLVM IRBuilder::CreateGEP

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to generate LLVM bitcode to store integer value into an integer array m.

At this point, I can generate bitcode for int global m

```
@m = common global <6 x i32>
```

Inside of function (foo) translation, I am trying to produce bitcode that reads the value stored in this vector, where the index is one from the first integer argument.

```
Value *m = TheModule->getGlobalVariable("m");
Value *offset = fooFunc->arg_begin();
Value *gep = Builder.CreateGEP(m,offset);
gep->dump();
```

Well, the output from the `gep->dump()` is simply `@m = common global <6 x i32>`. It seems that I am not using CreatGEP correctly. Can anyone advise me how to correctly produce the bitcode?

Comment: The `extractelement` instruction is what you want. See https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ExtractElementInst.html

Comment: I'd try a GRP with 2 indices, `0,0`.

Comment: 2 indices works! Thank you!